# NameError: name 'mostrar_urls' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, tkinter

Boa tarde! 

Estou tentando desenvolver um projeto/ideia que tive, só que quando fui colocar o "***menubar***" em outras "*partes do programa*" o programa não "*quer*" rodar mais, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse erro?

**Erro:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "ajuda_redes.py", line 21, in ajuda_redes
    ajuda.add_command(label='URLs', command=mostrar_urls)
NameError: name 'mostrar_urls' is not defined
```

Sim, eu dei `from import mostrar_urls *` em *ajuda_redes.py*

E sim, os arquivos *mostrar_urls.py* e *ajuda_redes.py* estão na mesma pasta.

EDIT(1): 
 
 **Erro:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep-web-url-aleatoria-develop/src/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mostrar_urls import mostrar_urls
  File "deep-web-url-aleatoria-develop/src/mostrar_urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ajuda_redes import ajuda_redes
  File "deep-web-url-aleatoria-develop/src/ajuda_redes.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mostrar_urls import mostrar_urls
ImportError: cannot import name 'mostrar_urls' from 'mostrar_urls' (deep-web-url-aleatoria-develop/src/mostrar_urls.py)
```

EDIT(2):

Pessoal, consegui resolver o(s) erro(s), troquei os *"trechos"* que estavam *"dando erro"*:

`from arquivo_exemplo import funcao_exemplo`

p/ `import funcao_exemplo`

`exemplo.add_command(label='exemplo', command=funcao_exemplo)`

p/ `exemplo.add_command(label='exemplo', command=arquivo_exemplo.funcao_exemplo)`

Eu só não entendi  o porquê que não consigo colocar nos três arquivos (`main.py`, `mostrar_urls.py` e `ajuda_redes.py`) da outra forma (recomendada pelo *[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)*):

```
from arquivo_exemplo import funcao_exemplo
exemplo.add_command(label='exemplo', command=funcao_exemplo)
```

Dessa forma *"dá"* o **ImportError** do **EDIT(1)**, a não ser que seja colocada apenas no `main.py`.

Comment: Se você precisa linkar uma *branch* inteira na sua pergunta, você precisa urgentemente ler sobre como criar um [mcve].

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, ok, agradeço pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira é especificar a função que quer utilizar do arquivo `arquivo_exemplo` assim: `from arquivo_exemplo import função_que_quero_chamar`. Neste caso, quando for chamar a função, não precisa apontar de onde ela vem. No seu caso, basta fazer:

```
from mostrar_urls import mostrar_urls
...
ajuda.add_command(label='URLs', command=mostrar_urls) # continua igual
```

Note que esta maneira segue as boas práticas definidas pela PeP8, como pode ser visto [aqui](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), pois deixa claro os nomes das funções importadas.

Comment: agradeço pela resposta, principalmente sobre a menção ao _[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)_, mas agora está "_dando_" outro erro =/  
irei editar o "corpo da pergunta", já que não dá p/ colocar o erro "_atual_" completo aqui.

Comment: Sobre o exemplo do `from arquivo import *`, acredito que esteja enganado quando ao uso da `arquivo.funcao_somar(1, 2)`, por exemplo. Quando se usa o "*", apenas devemos por o nome da função. Ou seja, no meu meu exemplo a chamada correta seria `funcao_somar(1, 2)`.

Comment: Realmente @Breno, obrigado por apontar.